# OAuth/OIDC support in ASP.NET Core Identity Provider Preview for Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

There is now support for ASP.Net Core Identity Provider in AWS Cognito ([announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-asp-net-core-identity-provider-preview-for-amazon-cognito/), [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/)).

However it is not clear whether OAuth/OIDC is supported.
p.s. also opened an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/issues/26) on the library's github page.

Answer (score 0):

`ASP.NET Core Identity Provider` is separate from OAuth/OIDC; basically it provides a MS interface for interacting with AWS Cognito (storing user data).

OAuth/OIDC could be provided; but it is not directly related to the user storage.